# How to get difference between dates in different timezones using moment?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I'm using momentJS to get difference between 2 dates. Here is my code:

```
const createdAt = "2019-11-15 09:45:21"; // Sample data from mysql database

// Add time since created
const created = moment(createdAt);
const now = moment();
// get the difference between the moments
const diff = now.diff(created);
//express as a duration
const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);
const days = diffDuration.days().toString().padStart(2, 0);
const hours = diffDuration.hours().toString().padStart(2, 0);
const minutes = diffDuration.minutes().toString().padStart(2, 0);
```

With that code, I can properly get the days, hours and minutes difference. The server where mysql is installed is in the Philippines and the `createdAt` value is automatically generated by mysql.

Now when I try to change my PC's timezone, I get incorrect date difference. I get negative values.

I tried doing something like adding `utc()`:

```
const created = moment.utc(createdAt);
const now = moment.utc();
```

And I still don't get any correct values. Am I missing something? Is it possible to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the time string from the database is Philippines time? In that case you need to create a `momentjs` object that reflects the appropriate time zone: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/k5zj4ha0/

Comment: @ChrisG I undestand that. Is it possible to make it dynamic? Like if you don't know where is the server running?

Comment: If the server doesn't store the time zone, how would that work? To determine the exact moment in time, you need to know in *which time zone* it is 9:45. The only alternative is to change the backend so all timestamps use UTC.

Comment: Chris's suggestion is the better alternative.  Your back-end timestamps should be UTC based.  Then you won't need to parse them as local time.  In general, one should code such that the time zone setting of the server should never affect the behavior of the application.

Comment: Also, you've not said much about the MySQL side of things.  Have you read about the differences between [`DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` types in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/datetime.html)?  Which type is your `createdAt` field?  How do you retrieve it?  Is it really a string by the time the rest of this code starts? Or were you just representing some other object (perhaps a JS `Date` object?)

Answer (score 1):

The `createdAt` time above is **not UTC format** so you will need to update the value by adding/subtracting the hours from your local time, or utc time. It's best to convert the relevant dates to UTC and then perform your [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) from there.

Take a look at the options below for parsing and values:

```js
// utc time now
const utcTime = moment.utc();
console.log(utcTime.toString());

// time recorded at server
const philliTime = moment('2019-11-15 09:45:21', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(philliTime.toString());

// need to add 8 hours as philli is +8 hours
philliTime.add(8, 'h');
console.log(philliTime.toString());

// options using parseZone
const optionBPhilli = moment.parseZone('2019-11-15 09:45:21 +08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');
console.log(optionBPhilli.toString());

const optionBUTC = moment.parseZone('2019-11-15 09:45:21 +00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');
console.log(optionBUTC.toString());

console.log(optionBPhilli.diff(optionBUTC, 'h'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For more info on parsing the string, check the [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) and also look at [UTC parsing.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Comment: One shouldn't ever be *adding* to adjust for time zone.  That creates a different moment in time.  The `parseZone` approach is better, but watch carefully the casing of those formatting tokens.  `h` is on a 12-hour clock.  `H` is on a 24-hour clock.  In this case, `HH` is more appropriate (given the leading zero).

Comment: (Also, UTC is not a "format".  I think you just mean that the input string doesn't contain any time zone or offset information.)

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson-Pint - updated the format as per your suggestion and after checking docs again.